# Node version is not updated on ubuntu

Tags: node.js

Npm commands is not running due to older version of npm on ubuntu then i try to update the node version but it is not updating.

I try so many commands but that's not working.

Comment: "I try to repair my car, and it dosnt work, can anyone help me?" You see how usefull such questions are? Please complete the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add details to your problem! No one is able to help you phrases like that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to install the `nvm (Node Version Manager)` and update the node and npm. NVM is basically a version management tool for Node JS.

[How to use node version manager (NVM) on ubuntu 20.04](https://asibin99.medium.com/how-to-use-node-version-manager-nvm-on-ubuntu-20-04-fa71c9929f51)

[NVM Commands Cheatsheet](https://duncanleung.com/nvm-commands-cheatsheet/)